# How can I add a wrapper on every two items in mustache loop?

Tags: mustache, patternlab.io

I am trying to get this outcome when looping through json in mustache

```
<div class="group">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</div>
```

This is the only thing I know how to do

```
{{# books }}
    <article> ... </article>
{{/ books }}
```

ps - I'm using pattern lab

Comment: Is it possible to change your array so that it's a 2d array ? This way you wil l have and array of arrays of 2 elements.

Comment: @O_Z well yes but I wandered it there was a way to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintainer of Pattern Lab Node here.

My suggestion is similar to O_Z's comment in that changing the data to utilize listitems.json might be a better bet.

You can read it all here: http://patternlab.io/docs/data-listitems.html

If you really want paired items like that, the gist would be having a template then like this:

```
{{# listItems.three}}
<div class="group">
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
</div>
{{/ listItems.three}}
```

where your `listitems.json` would correspond as:

```
{
  "1": {
    "articles" : [
       {...},
       {...}
    ]
  },
  "2": {
    "articles" : [
       {...},
       {...}
    ]
  },
  "3": {
    "articles" : [
       {...},
       {...}
    ]
  }
}
```

`listitems.three` has no link to the number of outputted articles, just the potential pook of data. With this approach, the order of itemization is actually randomized each build too.